# Why do I get the error message: NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

When I run ruby on rails program, get the error message:undefined method `action' for StaticPagesController:Class

application_controller.rb

```
require_relative '../models/pet'

class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base


  get '/' do
    #home
    erb :index
  end
  get '/questions' do
    erb :questions
  end
post '/results' do 
  @dog=get_results(params)

  erb :results
end
end
```

Here is my static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
     # Renders static_pages/swalton2html.erb by default.
  end

   def questions
    # Renders static_pages/swalton2html.erb by default.
  end
```

Comment: What the heck are you doing? Why does your `ApplicationController` inherit from `Sinatra::Base`? And why are you declaring the routes in your ApplicationController Sinatra style? Mixing the two sounds like a ridiculous idea.

Comment: @max I am new to ruby on rails.

Comment: @user2803053 do you want to use Ruby on Rails or do you want to use Sinatra?  They are two separate things.

Comment: @Eric Terry Oh, ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would benefit from reading the [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) for Ruby on Rails.

Basically your controller structure, routing and (probably) views are working more against you than for you. Using Rails generators to see how things should be organized might be helpful.

Comment: Is there anyway to fix the code  that I already have,  instead of starting over.

Comment: Yeah maybe - but maybe you should start with a decent tutorial instead - if you have mixed Sinatra and rails whilly nilly than you most likely have a real mess.